# Finding the last ten digits of \$\sum_{n=1}^{1000} n^n\$

Tags: java, programming-challenge, mathematics

This is my solution to [**Project Euler Problem 48**](https://projecteuler.net/problem=48).

**Problem:**

> The series, \$1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + ... + 10^{10} = 10405071317\$ .
>
> Find the last ten digits of the series, \$1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + ... + 1000^{1000}\$.

I would like feedback/advice to possibly increase efficiency and/or correct incorrect practices.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger start, sum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        start = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
        sum = sum.add(start.pow(i));
    }
    String sumStr = sum.toString();
    System.out.println(sumStr.substring(sumStr.length() - 10));
}
```

Comment: Hint: Use number theory to simplify the series modulo 10^10

Comment: I second that. Project Euler are *not* programming problems. They aren't even algorithm problems. They are maths problems. Most of them can be extremely simplified by using a little bit of number theory or combinatorics.

Comment: @JörgWMittag In my experience the mathy approaches optimize the performance, but they rarely simplify the code. The OP's code is short, easy to understand and runs in a fraction of a second. I'd only switch to mathy approaches when summing tens of millions of numbers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **Use the right data type.** The last ten digits of the sum is same as the sum modulo \$10000000000 = 10^{10}\$, which is smaller than \$2^{34}\$. All computations can be comfortably done with 64-bit integers; invoking `BigInteger` is a definite overkill. Extracting ten digits via string operations is also quite suboptimal.
- **Reuse your computations.** Once you computed \$k = n^n\$, use it to compute \$(2n)^{2n} = 2^{2n} n^{2n} = 2^{2n}k^2\$.
- **Devise an algorithm.** The logic of the previous bullet applies to any \$mn\$: \$(mn)^{mn} = m^{mn}n^{mn} = (m^m)^n (n^n)^m\$. This observation lends itself to the scheduling of computations very close to be optimal. Think about divisibility in general and prime numbers in particular.
- Any multiple of 10 raised to the corresponding power is surely divisible by \$10^{10}\$, and can be safely omitted from summation, but this is a minor optimization.

Comment: All your proposed changes unnecessarily complicate the code which is already fast enough (My C# port takes 70ms and goes down to 2ms using the `modPow` optimization). So I'd only do them if you really want to view the problem as a math problem and not as a coding problem.

Answer (score 2):

- The scope of `start` is larger than necessary
- The name of `start` is misleading, it should be something like [`base`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(exponentiation)) or perhaps `bigI`/`iBig` since it's just the big integer representation of `i`.
- Personally I'd eliminate it entirely, inlining the `BigInteger.valueOf(i)`
- I don't like using a single variable declaration, where some of the variables get initialized and some don't.
- You can use `BigInteger.modPow` with a modulus of 10^10, but for the small numbers you're dealing with, that might be considered premature optimization since the original code is already fast enough (70ms vs 2ms in my C# test)
- I'd replace your string manipulation with a modulus operation